# jinja2 navigate dynamically to json object

Tags: json, ansible, jinja2

My question looks trivial but I already spend some hours on it.

How to dynamically navigate into a json variable, with jinja2.
ex: I get

```
ansible_lvm.vgs:
    "vgs": {
                "vgdata": {
                    "free_g": "16",
                    "size_g": "0"
                },
                "vgswap": {
                    "free_g": "0",
                    "size_g": "00"
            }
        }
```

In a jinja2 structure I would like to get "free_g" attribut for "vgdata":
None of the code hereafter works:

```
   {% set my_vg_name = 'vg_data' %}
   {% set my_vg_size = ansible_lvm.vgs.(my_vg_name).free_g %}
   {% set my_vg_size = ansible_lvm.vgs.{{my_vg_name}}.free_g %}
   {% set my_vg_size = ansible_lvm.vgs|selectattr(my_vg_name, 'free_g') %}
```

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I hope that code snippet at the top is just an example, and not really what you are using, since it's malformed JSON. And I hope you are not actually asking the `vgs` object for `vg_data` when the key is `vgdata`, because that will never end well.

That aside:

You access `dict` objects in python using `vgs[my_vg_name]` syntax, or if you aren't sure that `vgs` contains that key, `vgs.get(my_vg_name, {})` to provide an empty `dict` as the default if `vgs` does not contain a key whose value is in the `my_vg_name` variable.

Perhaps it's just a bad question, but if you always want `vgdata.free_g` then why the dynamic access at all?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, impossible to do that with jinja2, I ll switch to python. vgs.get(my_vg_name, {}) is perfect.

Comment: **Impossible?!** `ansible -v -c local -i localhost, -m debug -e '{"thingy": {"joe": "alpha"}}' -a 'msg={{ thingy.get("frankie", "hollywood") }} verbosity=0' '*'`